# Why does adding datatemplate stop the display of itemsource?

Tags: xamarin, datatemplate

This code results in a display of the same line of the table name for every one of the 230 records in the table but not the fields:

```
ListView lv = new ListView();
        lv.ItemsSource = await App.Database.GetItemsAsync();
        StackLayout sl = new StackLayout();
        
        Label ln = new Label();
        ln.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, nameof(ContactsModel.LastName));
        Label fn = new Label();
        fn.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, nameof(ContactsModel.FirstName));
       
        sl.Children.Add(ln);
        sl.Children.Add(fn);
        sl.Children.Add(lv);
        Content = sl;
```

But adding the datatemplate results in a blank screen

```
ListView lv = new ListView();
            lv.ItemsSource = await App.Database.GetItemsAsync();
            var template = new DataTemplate(typeof(ViewCell));
            lv.ItemTemplate = template;
            StackLayout sl = new StackLayout();
            
            Label ln = new Label();
            ln.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, nameof(ContactsModel.LastName));
            Label fn = new Label();
            fn.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, nameof(ContactsModel.FirstName));
           
            sl.Children.Add(ln);
            sl.Children.Add(fn);
            sl.Children.Add(lv);
            Content = sl;
```

Comment: Is `ViewCell` your own type or just the default one? If the latter, why do you expect it to show anything? Also, how about using a ViewModel for this?

Comment: as @Cheesebaron points out, you are using an empty ViewCell as a template.  So of course it won't display anything.  You need to add content to it.  Your two Label controls are being added to the StackLayout that contains your list, not to the template.

Comment: Thanks for identifying the issue. Please help me by explaining how I add content, in this case, my two labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, this would be easier to do in XAML.  But if you need to do it in code

```
var template = new DataTemplate(() =>
{
    Label ln = new Label();
    ln.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, nameof(ContactsModel.LastName));
    Label fn = new Label();
    fn.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, nameof(ContactsModel.FirstName));
        
    var stack = new StackLayout();
    stack.Children.Add(ln);
    stack.Children.Add(fn);

    return new ViewCell { View = stack };
});

lv.ItemTemplate = template;
```

Comment: I wish  could do it in XAML but it is not an option